# Let $f(z)$ be continuous at $z$. Show that $\int^1_0 f(z+t\Delta z)dt\rightarrow f(z)$ as $\Delta \rightarrow 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be continuous at $z$.  Show that $\int^1_0 f(z+t\Delta z)dt\rightarrow f(z)$ as $\Delta \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\int_0^1 f(z+t\Delta z)\,dt-f(z)\right|\le\int_0^1 \left|f(z+t\Delta z)-f(z)\right|\,dt$$

Comment: @Dr.MV...i did't get your point

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $z$.

Comment: @Dr.Mv..i am really stuck i dint get .sorry

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous at $z$, then given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z+ \Delta z)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $| \Delta z|<\delta$.  Since $t\in [0,1]$, then certainly $|t\Delta z|<\delta$.

Comment: @Dr.Mv..thank u so much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!